# htmlAttributes: in Html.LabelFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I created scaffolded view for `Northwinds DB's product` table. I understood that it is creating anonymous type at `new {@class...`. But, I didn't understand portion `htmlAttributes:` in the following code. What is it doing?

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.UnitsInStock, 
    htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
```

And how is it different from `new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }` this code? I hope I asked question properly. I'm using MVC 5 with Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Its just passing the `new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" }` object to the `htmlAttributes` parameter of the extension method. And you could also use `@Html.LabelFor(model => model.UnitsInStock, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })` (i.e. without explicitly using `htmlAttributes:`)

Comment: Is it named parameter feature in c#?

Comment: .. to clarify further html attributes are passed using named parameter `htmlAttributes:`. That's (one of the great) feature in C#. More info https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx

Comment: @StephenMuecke I guess OP is clear now. You can convert above comments in Answer and OP can close the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`htmlAttributes:` is specifying a named parameter, so it is passing the anonymous object (`new { @class = "control-label col-md-2"`) to the `htmlAttributes` parameter of the `LabelFor()` method.

In this case its not strictly necessary because the `LabelFor()` has an [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.labelextensions.labelfor(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LabelExtensions.LabelFor%60%602%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper%7B%60%600%7D,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression%7BSystem.Func%7B%60%600,%60%601%7D%7D,System.Object%29) which accepts just the expression and the `object` so it could also have been just

```
Html.LabelFor(m => m.UnitsInStock, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
```

but using named parameter allows you to specify the parameters of a method in any order.

Refer also the documentation for [Named and Optional Arguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)